# Need help identifying SMD diodes

Tags: diodes, identification, components, surface-mount

Could someone help me to find product names of these diodes.
The search did not give clear results.
One of them is marked as s1y
[image: S1Y]

And second is seems 05 with rotated J and it has dot under 05.
[image: 05j]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note, alphabetic case often matters in SMD codes; `s1y` could be different from `S1Y`, `S1y`, etc.  And would you believe, there is a `0O` and `O0` marking, being (different voltage!) zener diodes.  What a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ones at the top are [1N4148s](https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/1/n/1n914bws%2C_1n4148ws%2C_1n4448ws_fairchild.pdf), the others at the bottom might be [5V1 zeners](https://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/b/z/bzx384_series_nxp.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Rohat! Seems that s1y is indeed 1N4148s.
Not really sure about 5V1 zener, at least I don't see any related marking code in the data sheet. 
How did you identify this component?

Comment: @KirillMonocle Take a look at [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd). To me, the marking of the diodes at the bottom looks like **D5**, not 05 *(And also the s-manuals list does not contain any diodes under 05)*. Check p.2 from the datasheet I linked and you'll see that D5 is for 5V1 Zener.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that's makes sense. This is definitely D5.